# Rails Eager loading (includes) and where clause is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, eager-loading

I'm using Rails 4.1 and my Models something like:

```
Client has_many TicketLists
TicketList has many projects
```

Now I'm trying to use eager loading in Client model something like:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  def ticket_lists_with_project_id(project_id)
    ticket_lists.includes(:projects).where("projects.id = ?", project_id)
  end  
end
```

And when I do:

```
Client.find(2).ticket_lists_with_project_id(1)
  Client Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."is_destroyed" = 'f' AND "clients"."is_closed" = 'f' AND "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "projects"
LINE 1: ...d" = 'f' AND "ticket_lists"."client_id" = $1 AND (projects.i...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "ticket_lists".* FROM "ticket_lists"  WHERE "ticket_lists"."is_destroyed" = 'f' AND "ticket_lists"."client_id" = $1 AND (projects.id = 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "projects"
LINE 1: ...d" = 'f' AND "ticket_lists"."client_id" = $1 AND (projects.i...
```

Comment: Try this instead: `ticket_lists.joins(:projects).where("projects.id = ?", project_id)`

Comment: @Surya Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
ticket_lists.includes(:projects).where("projects.id = ?", project_id)
```

do this:

```
ticket_lists.joins(:projects).where("projects.id = ?", project_id)
```

Since you're using Rails 4, you can make it look more cuter:

```
ticket_lists.joins(:projects).where(projects: {id: project_id})
```

Comment: This is awesome. You are the man. Not sure about using the scope tho as I'm trying to use the method as an instance method and not something like Client.ticket_lists_for_project you know.

Comment: Btw any golden role of where to use includes and where to use joins?

Comment: Here you go buddy: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Answer (score 11):

Try the below :

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  def ticket_lists_with_project_id(project_id)
    ticket_lists.includes(:projects)
                .where("projects.id = ?", project_id)
                .references(:projects)
  end  
end
```

It will work. If you want to [add conditions](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) to your included models you’ll have to explicitly reference them. Also *note* that `includes` works with association names while `references` needs the actual table name.

Comment: IMO, this is the right answer. I need `includes`, not `joins`. Thanks for the `references` tip.

Comment: According to [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)(see section 13.2) this query should return all ticket_lists regardless they have a project or not. Meaning, should make a left outer join. However, it is not working as expected. It behaves as if it is making an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
Client.includes(:ticket_lists => :projects).where("clients.id = ? ", 2)
```

OR

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  def ticket_lists_with_project_id(project_id)
    Client.includes(:ticket_lists => :projects).where("projects.id = ?", project_id)
  end  
end
```

Comment: He's trying to find ticket lists isn't he? You're returning clients.

Comment: Thanks for willing to help, how can I use it as an instance method and use it with something like 'Client.find(2).ticket_lists_with_project_id(1)' ?

Comment: I have changed your instance method. Please check

Comment: it does, thanks for the help but I prefer Surya solution as less code involves :P

Comment: have you checked number of queries for both solutions?